# Force download remotely hosted images to browser

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, image, download

Suppose I have an image hosted with Google: https://www.google.ae/images/srpr/logo11w.png

I want to make this image file download instead of opening directly in the browser.

I have tried:

```
<?php
function downloadFile($file, $type)
{
header("Cache-Control: public");
header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$file");
header("Content-Type: $type");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
header("Content-Length: ".filesize($file));
readfile($file);
}
downloadFile("img.jpg", "image/jpg");
?>
```

This works but only for locally hosted imges, not for images hosted remotely like the Google example, above.

Comment: you can't control how another server handles requests.

Comment: "Doesn't work" isn't much of a problem statement. Turn the PHP error reporting up as high as it will go and look in your logs.

Comment: yes right but is there any chance there like using js or anything to accomplish this?

Comment: @quentin it works but for the images hosted on the home server it doesn't handle images hosted on other server

Comment: if image is in already browser can convert to base 64, if it is just a link you could proxy through your server. Not much explained in question about use case

Comment: @ charlietfl but conversion into base64 require html 5 i guess which is again will not work in ie6,7 etc and will you pls elaborate that proxy thingy you mentioned

Comment: convert links href to point at download script in php. Pass the original url as a query param. If the param exists get the file using CURL. Can convert the href using javascript or php, whichever is more convenient.

Comment: basically it will store img on my server than will transfer. it will increase load on my server. any other optn?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The very first example on the [readfile() manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php) is titled 'Forcing a download using readfile()', with a `.gif` file:

```
$file = 'monkey.gif';

if (file_exists($file)) {
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
    readfile($file);
    exit;
}
```

Under the *Notes* section is the following tip:

> A URL can be used as a filename with this function if the fopen wrappers have been enabled. See fopen() for more details on how to specify the filename. See the Supported Protocols and Wrappers for links to information about what abilities the various wrappers have, notes on their usage, and information on any predefined variables they may provide.

So if you simply substitute `$file = 'https://www.google.ae/images/srpr/logo11w.png';` for `$file = 'monkey.gif';` the above script should force the image download.

Of course, the big drawback with this approach is that the image is transferred to your server first, and then downloaded to the client. But, as [@charlietfl wrote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26589020/force-download-remotely-hosted-images-to-browser#comment41792981_26589020) 'you can't control how another server handles requests.' so you can't link directly to the original source and expect the file to download.